# Change data range in a chart using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

It has been hours that I'm struggling with what I think to be a sible problem since Im not familiar at all with Chart object in VBA.

Here's my chart:

[image]

**What I want to do:** Change the data range of the two axis, the problem is that  cant figure out a way to edit the series of the chart.

Thanks four your help !

Comment: Have you tried the macro recorder?

Comment: You could use dynamic named ranges and no need for VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
With Workbooks(bookname).Charts(Chartname)
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(i).XValues = YourXs
    .SeriesCollection(i).values = YourYs
end with
```

You can choose which series you want to edit by using the index i. This actually sets the (X,Y) pairings while what's below only changes the range shown by the graph.

To change the bounds of your Y axis you can use

```
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale =
```

To change the bounds of your x axis use

```
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale =
```

Comment: Hey ! thanks for your help ! Unfortunately I still cant figure out what Im looking for. Is there no way of doing it by changing the Folrmula of the serie ? Something like: SeriesCollection.Formula = NewFormule ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to alter the data or change the range of the graphs? If you're trying to scale the y values, you might be able to get away with doing some operation on the seriesCollection(i).values and setting it equal back to itself

Comment: What Im trying to do is to change the range of the cells in the formula using VBA. for example the serie now is : 
=SERIES("SO2 U5";'CEMS_U6_YTD 2018 '!$B$2165:$B$2303;'CEMS_U5_YTD 2018'!$D$2165:$D$2312;1)

I want to change it using VBA to this : 

=SERIES("SO2 U5";'CEMS_U6_YTD 2018 '!$C$2165:$C$2303;'CEMS_U5_YTD 2018'!$D$2165:$D$2312;1)

It's just an example

Comment: You could accomplish that by using 


seriescollection(i).Xvalues=activeworkbook.sheets("CEMS_U6_YTD 2018").Range("C2165:C2303").values

and 

seriescollection(i).values=activeworkbook.sheets("CEMS_U6_YTD 2018").Range("D2165:D2312").values

Comment: Here's my code : 
Sub graphique()
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Trend")
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets("CEMS_U5_YTD 2018").Range("C1000:C1500").Values
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Sheets(1).Range("C6:C100").Values
End With
End Sub

It gives me an error 438 I dont know why :(

Comment: Oh my mistake, I think that you need to set them both to ranges not values. Try dropping the .Values from the right hand side of both lines

Answer (score 1):

You said you wanted to change

=SERIES("SO2 U5",'CEMS_U6_YTD 2018'!$B$2165:$B$2303,'CEMS_U5_YTD 2018'!$D$2165:$D$2312,1)

to this

=SERIES("SO2 U5",'CEMS_U6_YTD 2018'!$C$2165:$C$2303,'CEMS_U5_YTD 2018'!$D$2165:$D$2312,1)

This may be a simple as

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula = _
  "=SERIES(""SO2 U5"",'CEMS_U6_YTD 2018'!$C$2165:$C$2303,'CEMS_U5_YTD 2018'!$D$2165:$D$2312,1)"
```

note doubling of the double quotes around the series name.

However, since you are only changing the X values, you could use this:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='CEMS_U6_YTD 2018'!$C$2165:$C$2303"
```

or

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("CEMS_U6_YTD 2018").Range("$C$2165:$C$2303")
```

I've written a tutorial about editing series formulas with VBA: [Change Series Formula – Improved Routines](https://peltiertech.com/change-series-formula-improved-routines/).

Comment: Your Tutorial was great! Thank you.